# How to know when a webpage is updated?

Tags: updates, notifications, webpage

I'm looking for some way to know when a webpage is updated. This site it's really not very "web 2.0", doesn't have ajax, it seems like plain HTML.

I need a way to get an instant notification when the page is changed/updated.

Is there any app. to do that?

Thanks

Comment: This depends on the browser you're using, why don't you add that into the question?

Comment: It's not really possible to get an *instant* notification. You can just periodically check for updates and ask in very short intervals. But I don't think that's proper behavior on the internet. RSS feeds were invented exactly for problems like this.

Comment: It's just for one specific purpose, I don't mind checking between very short intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [NotiPage](http://www.notipage.com/en/index.php)

> NotiPage is a FREE webpages monitoring software. Once you've
>   configured a monitoring alert related to a specific webpage, NotiPage
>   will automatically check this webpage on a periodic basis until all
>   the set criteria are met. At that time, NotiPage will warn you by a
>   visual and audible alert.

Freeware, lightweight, recently updated. Can check every 1 minute.

Comment: It's empty now.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [ChangeDectection](http://www.changedetection.com/):

> ChangeDetection.com provides page change monitoring and notification
>   services to internet users worldwide. Anyone can use our service to
>   monitor any website page for changes. Just fill in the form below, we
>   will create a change log for the page and alert you by email when we
>   detect a change in the page text. We've been doing it since 1999. It's
>   free.

Comment: Tried to sign-up but I never got the activation email, or maybe it will take some time which makes me doubt about its capacity to send instant mail notifications when a webpage changes. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A FLOSS for GNU/Linux would be [Specto](http://specto.sourceforge.net/).

> Specto is a desktop application that will watch configurable events (such as website updates, emails, file and folder changes, system processes, etc) and then trigger notifications.
>
> For example, Specto can watch a website for updates (or a syndication feed, or an image, etc), and notify you when there is activity (otherwise, Specto will just stay out of the way). This changes the way you work, because you can be informed of events instead of having to look out for them. Better than clicking the refresh button on Caturdays, huh?

Answer (score 0):

GNU/Linux applications available for: Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora from their repositories:

- [urlwatch](https://thp.io/2008/urlwatch/) - Nice, [simple](https://youtu.be/JoFRJzW-QJg), easily [customizable](http://man.cx/urlwatch(1)) (via `~/.urlwatch/urls.txt`) Python script, tracking local and remote files. You can even pass [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) data and track output of shell commands - see example in `~/.urlwatch/urls.txt.example`. Output is in [unified diff format](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=164293). Can be used as job in cron (e.g. e-mail notification). No GUI.
- [specto](http://specto.sourceforge.net/) - Tracks e-mail (POP3, IMAP, and gmail), website changes (RSS & HTML), local files. GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script which performs wget to retrieve the page and md5checksum to create a hash of the page.  Then store the hash and have your script compare the last hash with a timestamp.