# Download/update webpages listed in XML sitemap

Tags: download, xml, sitemap

I'm searching a FLOSS tool that downloads all pages (and embedded resources, e.g. images) linked in a XML sitemap (built according to http://www.sitemaps.org/).

The tool should "crawl" the sitemap regularly and look for new and deleted URLs and changes in the `lastmod` element. So whenever a page gets added/deleted/updated, the tool should apply the changes.

Some sitemaps list sub-sitemaps in `sitemapindex`→`sitemap`. The tool should understand this and load all linked sub-sitemaps and look for URLs in there.

---

I know there are tools that allow me to extract all URLs from the sitemap, so that I could feed them to wget or similar tools (see for example: [Extract Links from a sitemap(xml)](https://superuser.com/q/466861/151741)). But this wouldn't help in getting noticed about updates to pages. [Tracking](https://superuser.com/a/461057/151741) the webpages itself for updates doesn't work, because "secondary" content on the pages changes daily, but `lastmod` gets only updated when relevant content changed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to script this with wget and cron? Look at wget's `--spider` flag. It looks to be all that you need, other than cron to run it occasionally.